# Access already deserialized properties from JsonConverter.ReadJson

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonconverter

I am trying to solve backward compartibility when deserializing old json. Previously there was `double` property and now it's changed to a custom type.

My idea is to read `double` and simply convert it using custom json converter.

Before was:

```
public class A
{
    [JsonProperty)]
    string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty)]
    double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Serialized as

```
{"Name":"test","Value":33.0}
```

New one:

```
public class A
{
    [JsonProperty]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyJsonConverter))]
    public MyType Value { get; set; }
}
```

Serialized as

```
{"Value":{"Value":33.0,"Name":"test", ...}},
```

Converter:

```
public class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => true;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value is double value)
            return new MyType(value, ???); // here is the problem, I need Name value here
        return reader.Value;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        JToken.FromObject(value).WriteTo(writer);
}
```

but to construct `MyType` I need string parameter which is a value of another property `Name`

How to access `Name` value from converter for `Value`? How to access anything what has been deserialized? Is there some kind of tree? Tokens tree?

Another thing: in `WriteJson` method I want to do "nothing" special, is my implementation correct? Or is there an easy way to prevent converter doing anything "special" upon serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to apply a converter to your parent `A` class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyJsonConverter))]
public class A
{
    public MyType Value { get; set; }
}

public class AConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(A);

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        // Check if the keys contains "Name"
        string name = jObject["Name"]?.ToString();

        var a = new A();

        if (name != null)
        {
            a.Value = new MyType
            {
                Name = name,
                Value = jObject["Value"].Value<double>()
            };
        }
        else
        {
            a.Value = jObject["Value"].ToObject<MyType>();
        }

        return a;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use default serailisation, just override `CanWrite` with `false`.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. I missed `CanWrite` property.  Is `CanConvert` check really needed? It was never called.

Comment: @Sinatr Not really, but it is marked as `abstract` and thus needs to be overridden.